# Change base of branch - git

Tags: git, branch

My current git tree looks like this:

```
                     / C -> D -> more commits
previous commits -> A -> B
                     \ C -> E -> more commits
```

where B and C are exactly the same (in terms of file changes) but they are different commits.

My question is can I make my tree look like this:

```
                          / D -> more commits
previous commits -> A -> B
                          \ E -> more commits
```

Thanks,
JamesStewy

P.S. sorry if this question is a duplicate, I couldn't think of a search term for this problem.

(EDIT) There are no more commits on the middle branch after B

Comment: You have two `C`s, I assume the top `C` and bottom `C` are also "different commit but same contents" as commit `B`?  This is just a rebase op—or more precisely, two separate rebases, one for each chain.  Git is normally smart enough to detect "same change, drop unneeded commit" automatically but if not you can direct rebase (with command line arguments, or by doing an interactive rebase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rebase` to (effectively) move parent node up the tree.

While on `D` branch: `git rebase (b-branch)`

While on `E` branch: `git rebase (b-branch)`

Substitute the appropriate branch names in (because it doesn't give them any names here).

Comment: Thanks, the definition of rebase I guess.